# Android search dialog onCancel not called when "up" icon clicked

Tags: android, search, dialog

My app has a search dialog and I need to detect when the dialog is cancelled.

The OnCancelListener is called if I tap outside the dialog or if I press the back button, but not with the up button at the left of the dialog.

Why, and how can I detect this?

Comment: Implement dialog.dismiss() in your up button Onclick listener

Comment: @GiruBhai The up button is part of the search dialog and I don't have access to it (that I know of).

Comment: Are you using custom dialog?Please post your code also

Comment: @GiruBhai I use the standard search dialog (invoked with `onSearchRequested`).

Answer (score -1):

Use setOnDismissListener on SearchManager:

```
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchManager.setOnCancelListener(new  OnCancelListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            } 
    }); 

    searchManager.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
        }

    });
```